# Is there a way to fill the subject line using select and using html only (without javascript, php, or any other source) just html?

Tags: html, mailto

Is there a way to fill the subject line using select and using html only (without javascript, php, or any other source) just html?

example below

```
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>&nbsp;
<a href="MAILTO:mymail@home.com?Subject="><b>Sign Up</b></a>
```

Comment: I believe you need javascript. Why cannot you use it? It's almost a oneliner with jQuery.

Comment: You will need to use javascript if you want the subject to be derived from the select box. Or, you could use images of the car manufacturers wrapped with a different a tag (and appropriate subject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use form tag with mailto schema:

```
<form method="get" action="mailto:myemail@exampe.com" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<select name="subject">
    <option value="Hello">Hello</option>
    <option value="Goodbye">Goodbye</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: +1 Nice hack. However I believe we should careful about mailto: links. Here's why: http://www.apptools.com/rants/mailto.php